# Fetch alternate series of records in SQL Server

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, entity-framework, linq

I want to get alternate series of records using SQL Server.

For example :

I want to skip first 10 records (1 to 10) in sequence and get other 10 records (11 to 20) after that I want to skip next 10 records (21 to 30) and get another next 10 records (31 to 40)

I have done for alternate rows as below...

```
SELECT ROW, EmployeeID 
FROM
    (SELECT 
         ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY EmployeeID) AS ROW, * 
     FROM Employee) A 
WHERE 
    ROW % 2 = 0
```

But in case of my requirement above logic will not work. Please help me to make above thing works..

Linq will also accepted

Thanks

Comment: Add sample data with expected output

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT ROW, EmployeeID 
FROM
    (SELECT 
         ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY EmployeeID) AS ROW, * 
     FROM Employee) A 
WHERE 
    ((ROW - 1)/10) % 2 = 1
```

Comment: Thanks! This is exactly which I want

Answer (score 0):

I have done above of your requirement like below (Example).

Generated 1200 number sequentially from 1 to 1200 like below

```
;WITH CTE
AS
(
SELECT 1 PERIOD_SID
UNION ALL
SELECT PERIOD_SID+1 FROM CTE WHERE PERIOD_SID<1200
)
SELECT * INTO #PERIOD1 FROM CTE
OPTION(MAXRECURSION 0)
```

After this i have find alternative numbers like you have mentioned in your query

```
SELECT PERIOD_SID FROM 
(
SELECT CASE
         WHEN PERIOD_SID%10 <> 0 THEN PERIOD_SID / 10
         WHEN PERIOD_SID%10 = 0 THEN ( PERIOD_SID / 10 ) - 1
       END RNO,
       PERIOD_SID
FROM   #PERIOD1 )A
WHERE RNO%2=0
```

so if you have sequential numbers in your query (If you dont have generate using rownumber) then apply above logic.

Your query need to convert like below.

```
SELECT EMPLOYEEID
FROM  (SELECT Row_number()
                OVER (
                  ORDER BY EMPLOYEEID)AS ROW,
              *
       FROM   EMPLOYEE) A
WHERE  ( CASE
           WHEN RNO%10 <> 0 THEN RNO / 10
           WHEN RNO%10 = 0 THEN ( RNO / 10 ) - 1
         END )%2 = 0
```

Answer (score 0):

may be you can try this

```
SELECT ROW, EmployeeID FROM(
SELECT ROW_NUMBER()OVER (ORDER BY EmployeeID)AS ROW,* FROM Employee)
A WHERE ((ROW - (ROW%10))/10) % 2 = 1
```

Don't if this works or not coz I dont have sql server to run. Please show the error/result after running this query.

Ask if any doubt.

Comment: Thanks! but there is small mistake in your answer. So I am getting wrong result. Please compare your answer with accepted answer.

Comment: yeah, sure. As I said I dont have sql server to run this.